# Running own identity service

Tags: c#, authentication, openid, dotnetopenauth, openid-provider

does dotnetopenauth allows or has the ability to run own identity server?

We are interested in building a id provider such as stack exchange, google, or fb.

As well as authentication, we are interested in allowing users to register and then using same creds, accessing corps any resource without login again and again.

what s the best place to start? any source code to research for such impl?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, indeed it does!

Best place to start would be the samples included on GitHub.

[**OpenID Provider**](https://github.com/DotNetOpenAuth/DotNetOpenAuth.Samples/tree/master/src/OpenID/OpenIdProviderMvc)

This example will show you the basics for setting up an OpenID provider.

[**OAUTH**](https://github.com/DotNetOpenAuth/DotNetOpenAuth.Samples/tree/master/src/OAuth)

An example of protecting an API with OAUTH - including an example implementation of an Authorisation Server

---

Have a look, it's a deep dive but worth it if you are serious about being an ID provider - a decision which should not be taken lightly. If you need help then search/post back here on [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dotnetopenauth), post on the [Google Groups](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/dotnetopenid) or talk in the [JabbR room](https://jabbr.net/#/rooms/DotNetOpenAuth)